# enable disable checkbox but not all

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple checkbox i want to disable other checkbox(i.e `Student`, `Parent`, `Faculty`) if i select `All` but if I select `Student` or others the `All` checkbox only will be disabled

```
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="All">ALL</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Student">Student</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Parent">Parent</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Faculty">Faculty</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Others">Others</input>
```

Comment: You need use some of JS to do that!

Comment: And the question is? You can control them via custom attributes that are set when the markup is composed by the server, something like `data-ignore="true"`, but you still need to learn how to compose selectors.

Comment: Or a better option, go for Select2 multiple input. A lot smoother, easier to work with and easier to parse input on the server.

Comment: @NhaHoang I can't use type="radio" because I have to select combination of multiple values e.g Student and Parent

Comment: Hi @CesarWencester I updated my ans, and recommend you to use some of js to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use same name but different ID's to disable your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="All" id="all">ALL</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Student" id="student">Student</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Parent" id="Parent">Parent</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Faculty" id="Faculty">Faculty</input>
<input type="checkbox" name="scope[]" value="Others" id="others">Others</input>
```

and you can use JavaScript to disable checkbox.

```
document.getElementById("others").disabled = true;
```